# Moving files from Public folder to C: takes a minute, even though they are same hard drive and same partition?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a big file, like 2GB, and would like to move it from

```
Network -> Bookroom -> Users -> Public
```

(this is the computer in the bookroom in the house)

to

```
c:\myfiles
```

and they are actually on the **SAME** hard drive (and same partition).  But <strike>copying</strike> moving still takes a minute or so?

I thought if on the same hard drive and partition, then it is a "move" and it should take 2, 3 seconds only.

that public folder also is \\Bookroom\Users\Public

**Update:**  Sorry, I actually mean "move" all the way...  so it is not copy but move.  So that's why I thought it should take 2, 3 seconds only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are accessing the file via a network share, even though the file is actually located on your computer. If that is the case then the move procedure does not know that the source and destination are on the same partition and will use the slower method.

Comment: is there a direct way to get to the network share folder as a path starting from c: ?  I tried to look at the property of the network share and can't see a path on the drive.

Comment: @Jian Lin - net share from the command prompt should do it.

Comment: ah I see, so c:\user\public is usually the place...

Answer (score 1):

If you copy, it recreates the files and sets the permissions on them to inherit that of the parent. If you cut or drag/drop on the same volume, it moves them and keeps the original permissions.

Answer (score 0):

- GUI approach: navigate to the file you want to move starting in C:\ (and not via the network share, as sgmoore says). Right click on the file, click cut. Navigate in the same way to the destination directory, right click, click paste.
- CLI approach: `MOVE C:\path\to\file.ext C:\myfiles`